# iteratively associate values to variables in C# like python does for (red, green, blue) in [2, 1, 3]

Tags: c#

think about the array [1, 2, 3] as one instance of his permutations.

In my code I need to associate this values to my variables so that I can refer them by name

I'm trying to obtain readable and simple code as Python version

In Python, if you have:

```
permutation = [2, 1, 3]
```

you can do:

```
for (red, green, blue) in permutation
for (a, b, c) in permutation
if b is red
```

...

**what I need to do is associate values in a particular permutation to variables in the exact same order: if I have [2, 1, 3] permutation and (red, green, blue) variables I want to happend 
red = 2
green =1
blue = 3**

I think in C# something like that can be accomplished by a Dictionary or an OrderedDictionary, maybe an ExtensionMethod with a meaningful name...
maybe something like colors["red"] == letters["a"] could be ok

I tryed  to sketch different implementations but I think I'm missing something
This is what I sketched:

```
enum ColorsEnum
{
    red, green, blue
}

public static Dictionary<string, int> Valorize(IEnumerable<string> keys, IEnumerable<int> values)
    {
           ...
    }

public static Dictionary<string, int> AsColorDictionaryWithValues(this string[] keys, int[] values)
{
           ...
}

public static void Valorize(Dictionary<string, int> dic, IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(typeof(ColorsEnum)))
    {
        dic.Add(item, [incremental_number]);
    }
}
```

What do you think can be a good solution (I care about readability and simplicity)

Comment: There are no good solutions. C# has simply no syntax sugar for tuples.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for an extension method like this?

```
public static void Do<T1, T2, T3>(this Tuple<T1, T2, T3> tuple,
                                  Action<T1, T2, T3> action)
{
    action(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3);
}
```

*Usage:*

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>
{
    Tuple.Create(255, 0, 0),
    Tuple.Create(0, 255, 0),
    Tuple.Create(0, 0, 255),
};

list.ForEach(t => t.Do((red, green, blue) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("R: {0}, G: {1}, B: {2}", red, green, blue);
}));
```

*Output:*

```
R: 255, G: 0, B: 0
R: 0, G: 255, B: 0
R: 0, G: 0, B: 255
```

Comment: what I need to do is associate values in a particular permutation to variables in the exact same order: if I have [2, 1, 3] permutation and (red, green, blue) variables I want to happend red = 2 green =1 blue = 3

Comment: I am ashamed to say that I didn't know so well the Tuple class... Thanks for your hint

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a fairly straight forward extension method, that I've called `ForEachBundle`, to do what you want.

So, for example, if you have this array:

```
var xs = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, };
```

Then you call `ForEachBundle` like so:

```
xs.ForEachBundle(
    (red, green, blue)
        => Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}", red, green, blue));
```

The result is:

```
1:2:3
4:5:6
```

I've assumed that if the enumerable had a seventh value in this example it would just ignore that "extra" value. Otherwise, if you needed to deal with this situation, you could modify my code to use default values or nullable types.

Here's my definition of `ForEachBundle`:

```
public static void ForEachBundle<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> @this,
    Action<T, T, T> action)
{
    if (@this == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException("@this");
    var a = action;
    if (a == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException("action");
    using (var en = @this.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (en.MoveNext())
            {
                var t0 = en.Current;
                if (en.MoveNext())
                {
                    var t1 = en.Current;
                    if (en.MoveNext())
                    {
                        var t2 = en.Current;
                        a(t0, t1, t2);
                    }
                    else break;
                }
                else break;
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this meets your requirements or not.

---

Here's a version that adds default values for incomplete "bundles":

```
public static void ForEachBundle<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> @this,
    Action<T, T, T> action)
{
    if (@this == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException("@this");
    var a = action;
    if (a == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException("action");
    using (var en = @this.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (en.MoveNext())
        {
            var t0 = en.Current;
            var t1 = en.MoveNext() ? en.Current : default(T);
            var t2 = en.MoveNext() ? en.Current : default(T);
            a(t0, t1, t2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what I need to do is associate values in a particular permutation to variables in the exact same order: if I have [2, 1, 3] permutation and (red, green, blue) variables I want to happend red = 2 green =1 blue = 3

Comment: @JackNova - That's exactly what my code does. `var xs = new [] { 2, 1, 3, };` gives `2:1:3` when run on my code.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. I tried your code and this is what I got: http://pastebin.com/jHt85zXj
to me it seems hard to read

Comment: It is my fault, I'm removing some curly brackets and it gets really good